# Change the visibility of a View while repeating data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, visibility, listitem

I am populating OrderHistory by retrieving data from Server in my app. Here I need to populate listitem depends on OrderId. If OrderId repeats I need to hide the LinearLayout which is marked in green in screenshot. Otherwise the Layout has to be usual view.Please help me.

[image]

MyAdapter Class:

```
public class MyOrderAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyOrderAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    Context mContext;
    List<CartRes> mOrderList = new ArrayList<>();

    private ImageLoader imageLoader;

    public MyOrderAdapter(Context context, List<CartRes> orderList) {
        mContext = context;
        mOrderList = orderList;

        Log.e("Json Adapter", "" + mOrderList);
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.my_order_history, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(v);

        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.cartResOrder = mOrderList.get(position);

        imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();

        String IMAGE_URL = "http://" + Config.IMAGE_URL + holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_IMAGE;
        Log.e("Image URL", IMAGE_URL + "  " + holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_IMAGE);

        imageLoader.get(IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.orderImage, 0, 0));

        holder.orderImage.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);


        holder.txtOrderId.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_ID);
        holder.txtOrderProduct.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_PRODUCT);
        holder.txtorderedDate.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_DATE);
        holder.txtDeliveredDate.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_DELIVERY_DATE);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mOrderList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView txtOrderId, txtOrderProduct, txtorderedDate, txtDeliveredDate;
        Button butDetail, butRemove;
        NetworkImageView orderImage;
        CartRes cartResOrder;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            txtOrderId = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderId);
            txtOrderProduct = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderProduct);
            txtorderedDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderedDate);
            txtDeliveredDate = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderDeliveredDate);

            butDetail = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderViewDetail);
            butRemove = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.orderRemove);

            orderImage = (NetworkImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.OrderproductImage);
        }
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**

```
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.cartResOrder = mOrderList.get(position);

    imageLoader = CustomVolleyRequest.getInstance(mContext).getImageLoader();

    String IMAGE_URL = "http://" + Config.IMAGE_URL + holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_IMAGE;
    Log.e("Image URL", IMAGE_URL + "  " + holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_IMAGE);

    imageLoader.get(IMAGE_URL, ImageLoader.getImageListener(holder.orderImage, 0, 0));

    holder.orderImage.setImageUrl(IMAGE_URL, imageLoader);

    holder.txtOrderId.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_ID);
    holder.txtOrderProduct.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_PRODUCT);
    holder.txtorderedDate.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_DATE);
    holder.txtDeliveredDate.setText(holder.cartResOrder.ORDER_DELIVERY_DATE);

    if (position > 0 && mOrderList.get(position).ORDER_ID == mOrderList.get(position - 1).ORDER_ID) {
        //make sure it is not the first one, and make sure it has the same ID as previous.
        holder.OrderLinear.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide it, you need to set the reference first.
        holder.txtOrderId.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Comment: could u show the code on how you currently output that?

Comment: Kindly check my code.

Comment: is the item displayed below linearlayout marked in green is in different layout and different item?

Comment: Instead of repeating same Order id as multiple time,I need to hide if it repeats.Otherwise it has to be shown

Comment: Yeah..That is different linearLayout below the green linearlayout @RajenRaiyarela

Comment: in any case best solution is to filter the List<CartRes> to only have single item for each order before passing to adapter. You can have two arraylist, one with all the data downloaded from server and another is filtered one with only items to be displayed.

Comment: any solution if we want to show an invisible item on the button click in this same condition !?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you could do it:

1. Have a new holder variable that refers to your `LinearLayout` you want to hide.
2. In your `onBindViewHolder()`

   ```
   @Override
   public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
       //setup everything else above...

       if (position > 0 && mOrderList.get(position).ORDER_ID == mOrderList.get(position - 1).ORDER_ID){
           //make sure it is not the first one, and make sure it has the same ID as previous.
           holder.thelinearlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE); //hide it, you need to set the reference first.
       }else holder.thelinearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           //if somehow order gets changed.(e.g. previous row is deleted).

   }
   ```

**EDIT**:

I'm assuming that the data inside is sorted by ORDER_ID, so there won't be a case where there are two elements with the same ORDER_ID that is not next to each other.

You might want to sort them based on ORDER_ID before passing the list into adapter.

**EDIT2:**

Added else condition as suggested in the comment.

Comment: it will not work if same `ORDER_ID` items are not next to another (author should precise this)

Comment: your way is simple and probably sufficient for Parama Sudha, lets wait for his comment :)

Comment: Please check my UPDATE. Is this right to get? I tried but didnt get what I expect result.

Comment: it should be right. What type is ORDER_ID? You might need to use `.equals()` to compare it.

Comment: Yeah after replacing == to .equals, successfully got the exact result.

Comment: @ParamaSudha Make sure in else condition you also again `Visible` your views.

Comment: `else holder.thelinearlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: what if after we want to show invisible item on button click after populating list?

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot does not tell that but if your view is RecyclerView or ListView then I'd preprocess the data prior feeding it to the adapter (i.e. by wrapping your model into another class with additional attributes).

Alternatively you can try checking previous row (by fetching it from your data source or adapter) while populating current one and adjust the view

Comment: It is RecyclerView

Comment: Then try the second approach first.

Answer (score 0):

maybe just add field `boolean repeatOrderId` to your `CartRes` class and in constructor do some `for` loop and flag all items? you may check also in runtime, but you have pretty fixed list, preparing in construtor this flag is better for performance

```
for(int i=0; i<mOrderList.getCount(); i++){
    CartRes cr = mOrderList.get(i);
    cr.repeatOrderId=true;
    for(int j=0; j<i; j++){
        if(cr.ORDER_ID==mOrderList.get(j).ORDER_ID){
            cr.repeatOrderId=false; //default true
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

then inside `onBindViewHolder` check this flag and `setVisibility(cr.repeatOrderId);` for desired layout

Comment: hope he's not gonna sort that list.

Comment: don't see any code for filtering/sorting, but if needed this code might be run after every list change (before `notifyDataSetChanged`), don't forget to "reset" this flag to `true` for all items before. Or like in answer: checking dynamically in `onBindViewHolder` (but his is not best practise)